# Network requests in Flutter app on physical iOS devices are slow

Tags: ios, flutter, http, dart, websocket

I am working on a cross-platform app using Flutter, for Android, iOS and Web. For some reason though, network requests on iOS are very slow.

The app works fine on Android and Web. The slow network requests don't seem to be due to performance issues; the UI works fast and I have sort of deduced (using a stopwatch) that the delay is always 10 seconds. The delay affects both HTTP (https://) and WebSocket (wss://) requests. Even more puzzling, the app runs fine on simulator devices. I have tried a variety of physical iOS devices but the result has been the same.

For context, I am using the Dart HTTP library (https://pub.dev/packages/http) for HTTP requests. Also, `flutter --version` gives

```
Flutter 2.6.0-6.0.pre.5 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 33755f203d (8 weeks ago) • 2021-09-05 13:16:01 -0700
Engine • revision dbc97a09b4
Tools • Dart 2.15.0 (build 2.15.0-82.0.dev)
```

Is this a known issue with Dart/Flutter? I am willing to provide specifics if needed for clarification.

Comment: All other applications or any web link works well in safari browser ? Have you checked your iOS device's low data mode is enable or not.

Comment: Yep, everything else works fine and low data mode is off. This issue is reproducible on different devices anyway.

Comment: @VictorDurojaiye, which Flutter version do you use? Do you still have the issue?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when pasting the result of `flutter --version`. Updated the question now. It is 2.6.0-6.0.pre.5.

Comment: Maybe private relay (obfuscating ip on iOS) is causing delay. I saw same behavior on my mac using open Wifi spots. I turned off private relay and the internet worked fine. This is not an issue in a secured wifi such as my home or work place.

Comment: Another point i noticed, on simulator it is running always fine (only on physical device it is slow) and have fast performance, i assume since it is using the internet / network connection of the macbook, it may have something like an "trusted" network connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this already so I'll post an answer in case anyone else has the same issue.

It turned out to be an IPv4 issue. I noticed that hosts with IPv6 support worked just fine, but my backend which used only IPv4 had this problem. Apparently, a Dart SDK issue was raised already and was fixed/resolved, but I still had the problem even after updating my installation (https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/41451#issuecomment-1003663129).

Switching to Cloudflare DNS and enabling IPv6 support solved the problem, although I presume it would still work with any other means of IPv6 support.